# Why trying to access the class name of a React component lead to ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, scope, lifetime

Here is my React component in `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

When I run this with `npm start` and visit http://localhost:3000/, I do get the desired output, "Hello, World!", in a web page. Now I right click on the page, select "Inspect" to open Chrome DevTools. In the Console, I type `App` but I get an error.

```
> App
(x) VM154:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Why is `App` not defined?

When I check "View Page Source", I see these source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  ...
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

When I view source of http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js, I see this in the source:

```
var App =
/*#__PURE__*/
function (_React$Component) {
...
```

So `App` should be defined in this page, right? Why do I still get `ReferenceError` when I try to access it in the DevTools Console?

I am aware that I can use React DevTools to debug React components. But that's not what my question is about. My question is about scope and lifetime of a class I have defined in React. Why does the `App` class definition not live when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing "App" in your console will try to access `window.App`, but `window.App` does not exist. App is a variable which is local to the module it is defined in. Your code gets transpiled by webpack, but after the transpilation it is still a local variable, it's just that's enforced by a closure rather than a module.

You have options though. Try setting a breakpoint in the code using the browser's developer tools. While it's paused there, typing in the console should be able to access local variables which are in scope at the spot it's paused.